# optimize query without using union

Tags: sql, oracle, optimization, union

I have below query which is generating from anonymous block. I can change anonymous block also if required.
The below query result is mentioned for year 2010 and the month of january but i am doing it for all the months. In this way i want to run this queries from 2009 till 2017 year by year.
The value for `ID_REC` is distinct and has 47 values. so for january it will generate 47 records.

The query is taking time more than 10 minutes to run at once for year by year. Is there any other way i can optimize this query and make it single query ?
I am using rownum to get the first record every time.

I dont have index on any of this columns.

```
SELECT   ID_REC,MONTH_ID,NAME,LOAD_SDT,LOAD_ID  from  TEST_REC_LIST where month_id = 201001 and ID_REC= 1 and rownum=1 union
```

Comment: Would this work? `SELECT   ID_REC,MONTH_ID,NAME,LOAD_SDT,LOAD_ID  from  TEST_REC_LIST  Where ID_REC IN (1,10,11,12....9) and month_id = 201001 and rownum=1`

Comment: as rownum = 1 its returning only one row

Comment: What is the purpose of `WHERE ... rownum = 1`? It will return an arbitrary non-determined row as you don't specify any `ORDER BY`.

Comment: for every ID_REC, rownum = 1 needs to be fetched

Comment: Yes, but which row? What do you consider as "one row"?

Comment: i have also mentione the output result for the first 2 months in question

Comment: for every ID_REC,MONTH_ID the LOAD_ID is distinct. So i can take it as arbitary for this reason i use rownum = 1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `row_number()` with `partition by`:

```
select id_rec, month_id, name, load_sdt, load_id
  from (select id_rec, month_id, name, load_sdt, load_id, 
               row_number() over (partition by id_rec order by null) as rn
          from test_rec_list 
          where month_id = 201001)
  where rn = 1;
```

Add `and id_rec in (1, 2, 3, 5....)` to `where` clause if you are interested only in particular `id_rec`s.

You could also change `where month_id = 201001` to `month_id between ... and ...` and include `month_id` in `partition by` to make everything in one query.

Change `order by null` to proper order if you have any key, perhaps `load_id` or date.

---

**Edit:** According to Your comments, Your query should be like:

```
select entity_id,month_id,sys_db_name,sys_load_dts,sys_load_id 
  from (select entity_id,month_id,sys_db_name,sys_load_dts,sys_load_id, 
               row_number() over (partition by entity_id, month_id order by rowid) as rn
          from int_pub_edw.dm_cust_purch_fl 
          where month_id between 201001 and 201012 and entity_id between 0 and 48)
  where rn = 1;
```

Do not use `row_number()` twice and do not omit `where rn = 1`, it's very important, here we get only one row for each id/month.

Table is hit once, no unions, everything in one query, if there are indexes on columns `entity_id` and `month_id` it should be fast.

Comment: i want monthid between 201001 till 201031. Can you please tell me how i can use that in partition and also whether it will optimize the performance ?

Answer (score 1):

What about this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    ID_REC, MONTH_ID, 
    FIRST_VALUE(NAME) OVER (PARTITION BY ID_REC, MONTH_ID ORDER BY ROWID) AS NAME, 
    FIRST_VALUE(LOAD_SDT) OVER (PARTITION BY ID_REC, MONTH_ID ORDER BY ROWID) LOAD_SDT, 
    FIRST_VALUE(LOAD_ID) OVER (PARTITION BY ID_REC, MONTH_ID ORDER BY ROWID) AS LOAD_ID
from TEST_REC_LIST 
where month_id = 201001 
   and ID_REC BETWEEN 0 and 48;
```

Comment: its returning duplicate records

Comment: Add DISTRICT keyword

Comment: i am not sure where i should add DISTINCT because for every ID_REC, rownum = 1 needs to be fetched. Also for group by clause its giving error as not group by expression

Comment: Normally it should rerturn 564 records as i have ID_REC 47 and 47 * 12(months) = 564 records